# How to transpose CSV data from a wide format to long dataset using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, transpose

I need to perform the below data transformation for an arbitrary number of "items" using Python. The first two columns are always the same, then there could be thousands of "itemN" columns, and I would want all the real-values in a new single column.

I have attempted to use pandas.wide_to_long but to my knowledge I would have put the new name into the transposed table, which wouldn't work if the number of items could change.

```
type   rid          item1 item2 item3
apple  [81]          1.1   1.1   1.1 
orange [82]          2.2   2.2   2.2 
banana [41,42,43,52] 3.3   3.3   3.3 
kiwi   [90,95]       4.4   4.4   4.4
```

to

```
type   rid             gid   value
apple  [81]           item1   1.1 
apple  [81]           item2   1.1 
apple  [81]           item3   1.1 
orange [82]           item1   2.2 
orange [82]           item2   2.2 
orange [82]           item3   2.2 
banana [41,42,43,52]  item1   3.3 
banana [41,42,43,52]  item2   3.3 
banana [41,42,43,52]  item3   3.3 
kiwi   [90,95]        item1   4.4 
kiwi   [90,95]        item2   4.4 
kiwi   [90,95]        item3   4.4
```

So far I have tried using a double for loop and index slicing with numpy arrays and using pandas.wide_to_long.

```
a = np.array([['apple'  ,tuple([81]) ,1.1 ,1.1 ,1.1] ,['orange' ,tuple([82]) ,2.2 ,2.2 ,2.2],['banana' ,tuple([41,42,43,52]) ,3.3 ,3.3 ,3.3],['kiwi' ,tuple([90,95]) ,4.4 ,4.4 ,4.4]])
names = ['type' ,'rid' ,'item1' ,'item2' ,'item3']
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=names)
```

Comment: Please share the data in a format that is easier for others to use.

Comment: I added an easy test example of code. pd.DF doesn't want to hash lists so I made them tuples. This example works as intended with the accepted answer.

Comment: I had forgotten all about this question, why are _thousands_ of columns? It seems strange for tabular data, no?

Comment: It is a poorly formatted government dataset which is storing each unit in its own column (so I agree it is strange, but hey blame the gov't). I wanted to change this in my DB so that each row was a unit and the columns were now the parameters. The top answer solved this problem well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the first 2 columns into the index, stack the resulting dataframe and then reset the index:

```
df.set_index(['type', 'rid']).stack().reset_index()
```

gives:

```
      type            rid level_2    0
0    apple           [81]   item1  1.1
1    apple           [81]   item2  1.1
2    apple           [81]   item3  1.1
3   orange           [82]   item1  2.2
4   orange           [82]   item2  2.2
5   orange           [82]   item3  2.2
6   banana  [41,42,43,52]   item1  3.3
7   banana  [41,42,43,52]   item2  3.3
8   banana  [41,42,43,52]   item3  3.3
9     kiwi        [90,95]   item1  4.4
10    kiwi        [90,95]   item2  4.4
11    kiwi        [90,95]   item3  4.4
```

Just rename the new columns, and that's done:

```
df.set_index(['type', 'rid']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2': 'gid',
                                   0: 'value'})
```

gives the expected dataframe.

Comment: Thank you so very much! This answer works perfectly. Saurav Joshi also had a great answer but I prefer this one just a little because it doesn't require me to keep the item names in an array and pass it to the pd.melt() function.

Comment: Just one thing I will note is that reset_index() doesn't seem to work if you already have a column name "0", just in case anyone else sees this. Not generally a big deal though.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+).

```
# Build a DataFrame identical to the first example data you provided
d = {'type': {0: 'apple', 1: 'orange', 2: 'banana', 3: 'kiwi'},
     'rid': {0: [81], 1: [82], 2: [41, 42, 43, 52], 3: [90, 95]},
     'item1': {0: 1.1, 1: 2.2, 2: 3.3, 3: 4.4},
     'item2': {0: 1.1, 1: 2.2, 2: 3.3, 3: 4.4},
     'item3': {0: 1.1, 1: 2.2, 2: 3.3, 3: 4.4}})
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Explode the 'rid' column and reset to default integer index
df.explode('rid').reset_index(drop=True)

     type rid  item1  item2  item3
0   apple  81    1.1    1.1    1.1
1  orange  82    2.2    2.2    2.2
2  banana  41    3.3    3.3    3.3
3  banana  42    3.3    3.3    3.3
4  banana  43    3.3    3.3    3.3
5  banana  52    3.3    3.3    3.3
6    kiwi  90    4.4    4.4    4.4
7    kiwi  95    4.4    4.4    4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to go with this would be the use of **pandas.melt()** function.

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['type', 'rid'], value_vars=['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])
```

Output:
[image]